# Calculus differentiate problem. L'hospital and logarithm involved.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve this question

[image]

This is what I did and I'm now clueless

[image]

Comment: Please do not link unsearchable images.  Instead, use *MathJax*.

Comment: Write the expression as $$ \left( \ \frac{x + 4}{x} \ \right)^{-x} \ \  = \ \ \left( \ 1 + \frac{4}{x} \ \right)^{-x} $$  instead:  this should be easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: As for the calculation you made, the differentiation "goes off the rails" when you got to $$  \frac{\frac{(x+4)}{x} \ · \ \frac{x + 4 - x}{(x+4)^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \ \ ,  $$ which should have become $$  -x · \frac{4} {(x+4) }  \ \ . $$   That then takes you to the correct natural logarithm of the "limit at infinity", $ \ -4 \ \ . $